# ffmpeg - Trimming multiple videos at once without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder where every mp4 file needs the first 10 minutes trimmed off. I'm using the following to trim on an individual basis, but it's taking too long to do one by one

`ffmpeg -i "untrimmed.mp4" -ss 00:10:00 -c copy "trimmmed.mp4"`

Is there an easy way to trim multiple video files at once?

Edit - I have since found a workaround in powershell - example using 11 minutes

`Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 | ForEach -Process { ffmpeg -i $_ -ss 00:11:00 -c copy ($_.BaseName + '_Trimmed.mp4')}`

Comment: Answer depends on your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called batch processing and the method depends on the system as ffmpeg lacks this capability in itself.

On Windows, you may want to use `ForFiles` to find files matching the pattern (e.g. `*.mp4`) and a `/C` switch to run the ffmpeg command on the results.

On Linux and in MacOS command line `find` does the same thing with the switch `-exec`.

In either case you can use loops, but they overcomplicate things when this is all you want to do.

For a Linux example, this command will search the current folder `.` for files with names matching `*.mp4` pattern, then execute ffmpeg for each result `{}`, outputting to e.g. `untrimmed.mp4_trim.mp4` (you can work with that, right?). The escaped `;` at the end closes the `-exec` switch:

`find . -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i '{}' -ss 00:10:00 -c copy '{}_trim.mp4' \;`